# Mean speed and root mean speed expressions. Maxwell Boltzman

Tags: thermodynamics, statistics

From my understanding, the mean squared speed are given by the following expressions:

$\langle v^2 \rangle = \langle v_x^2 \rangle + \langle v_y^2 \rangle + \langle v_z^2 \rangle $

$\langle v^2 \rangle= \langle v_x^2 + v_y^2 + v_z^2 \rangle$

However, I couldn't figure the expression for the mean speed of $\langle v \rangle$:

My guess were:

1. $\langle v \rangle = (\langle v_x \rangle^2 + \langle v_y \rangle^2 + \langle v_z \rangle^2)^{\frac{1}{2}}$ of

But that didn't seem to make any sense, as $\langle v_x \rangle = \langle v_y \rangle= \langle v_z \rangle = 0$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all the expression,
$$\langle v \rangle =(\langle v_x \rangle^2 +\langle v_y \rangle^2+\langle v_z\rangle^2)^{1/2}$$

It's wrong. As
$$v=\sqrt{v_x^2+v_y^2+v_z^2}$$
So taking mean value both side.
$$\langle v \rangle = \left\langle \sqrt{v_x^2+v_y^2+v_z^2}  \right \rangle  $$

---

> How to find $\langle v \rangle$?

To find mean value of velocity, you need to use distribution that velocity following, lets say it's $f(v)$, then mean value given by
$$\langle v\rangle=\frac{\int vf(v)dv}{\int f(v)dv}$$

If your gas is following [Maxwell-Boltzmann distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maxwell%E2%80%93Boltzmann_distribution) then you can put it in place of $f(v)$ and find out what's the mean is ( The full proof is on Wikipedia).

Note: In general if some random variable $x$ follow the distribution $f(x)$, then the mean value of any function of $x$, g(x), given by:

$$\langle g(x) \rangle=\frac{\int g(x)f(x)dx}{\int f(x)dx}$$

Answer (score 0):

You find the mean speed from the maxwell distribution function $f(v)dv$ itself as it is the expected value: $$<v> = \int_{0}^{\infty}vf(v)dv = 4\pi\left(\frac{m}{2kT\pi}\right)^{3/2}\int_{0}^{\infty}v^3e^{-\frac{mv^2}{2kT}}dv = \sqrt{\frac{8kT}{\pi m}}$$.